# When I change "module" in tsconfig.json to 'ESNext' and "type" in package.json to 'module', I get an error

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, ts-node

When I compile my TS code to JS, I want the JS to use ESNext import/export and not CommonJS import/export. When I change "module" in tsconfig.json to 'ESNext' and "type" in package.json to 'module' for this purpose, I get an error:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for G:\TechPro424\Other\Documents\GitHub\MultiBot\src\index.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:87:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:102:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:21:14)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:280:58)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:66:26)
    at ESMLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:297:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:261:34)
    at async Promise.all (index 0) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

`index.ts` is the file that I start to run the program.

***My tsconfig.json:***

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

        /* Projects */
        // "incremental": true,                              /* Enable incremental compilation */
        // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
        // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                          /* Specify the folder for .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation files. */
        // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects */
        // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
        // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */

        /* Language and Environment */
        "target": "ESNext",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
        "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
        // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
        // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
        // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
        // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h' */
        // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
        // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using `jsx: react-jsx*`.` */
        // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for `createElement`. This only applies when targeting `react` JSX emit. */
        // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
        // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */

        /* Modules */
        "module": "ESNext",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
        "rootDir": "./src",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
        "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
        // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
        // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
        // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
        // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like `./node_modules/@types`. */
        // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
        // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
        "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files */
        // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow `import`s, `require`s or `<reference>`s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */

        /* JavaScript Support */
         "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the `checkJS` option to get errors from these files. */
         "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
        // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from `node_modules`. Only applicable with `allowJs`. */

        /* Emit */
        "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
        "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
        // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
        "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
        // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If `declaration` is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
        "outDir": "./dist",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
        // "removeComments": false,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
        // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
        // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
        // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types */
        // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
        "sourceRoot": "./src",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
        // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
        // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
        // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
        // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
        // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
        // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have `@internal` in their JSDoc comments. */
        // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like `__extends` in compiled output. */
        // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
        // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing `const enum` declarations in generated code. */
        "declarationDir": "./Typings",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
        // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */

        /* Interop Constraints */
        // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
        // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
        "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */
        // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

        /* Type Checking */
        "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
        // "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied `any` type.. */
        // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account `null` and `undefined`. */
        // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
        // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for `bind`, `call`, and `apply` methods match the original function. */
        // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
        // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when `this` is given the type `any`. */
        // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Type catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
        // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
        // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when a local variables aren't read. */
        // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read */
        // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
        //"noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
        // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
        // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
        // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
        // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type */
        // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
        // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */

        /* Completeness */
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": false,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
        "skipLibCheck": false                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

***My package.json:***

```
    {
        "name": "multibot",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "description": "A multi-purpose bot without premiums.",
        "main": "dist/index.js",
        "type": "module",
        "private": true,
        "scripts": {
            "build": "tsc",
            "start": "nodemon"
        },
        "author": "TechPro424#5512, That Genz Gamer#6557",
        "repository": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git+https://github.com/TechPro424/MultiBot.git"
        },
        "bugs": {
            "url": "https://github.com/TechPro424/MultiBot/issues"
        },
        "homepage": "https://github.com/TechPro424/MultiBot",
        "license": "ISC",
        "dependencies": {
            "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
            "dotenv": "^14.2.0",
            "mongoose": "^6.1.8",
            "node-fetch": "2.6.1"
        }

}
```

Why is this? Please help me out.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you're transpiling it. You need to run tsc then nodemon. The error says it .. node can't run ts files

Comment: I run `ts-node ./src/index.ts --enable-source-maps` using nodemon.json @Phix

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove `"type": "module",`
Well it worked for me.

Comment: I get an error: https://gist.github.com/TechPro424/32b796d587760045de99e6fc985317cf